# Build a pyramid of stars using map function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written a simple javascript code to print pyramid of stars using for loop. Is it possible to write the code in a simplified manner using map function? Please suggest.

```js
// Program to build a `Pyramid of stars` of given height
const buildPyramid = (height) => {
  // Code to display stars in pyramid format
  let initialStapce = height;
  let starCount = 1;
  let result = '';
  for (let line = 1; line <= height; line = line + 1) {
    for (let leftStace = 0; leftStace < initialStapce; leftStace = leftStace + 1) {
      result = result + ' ';
    }
    for (let starNumber = 0; starNumber < starCount; starNumber = starNumber + 1) {
      result = result + '* ';
    }
    result = result + ' \n';
    initialStapce = initialStapce - 1;
    starCount = starCount + 1;
  }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`, yes, but I think string [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) based on the index is the bigger challenge. As you `map`, keep track of the index and pad your stars on the left and right accordingly:

```js
function pyramid(h) {
  return Array(h).fill('*')
    .map((s, i) =>
      ' '.repeat(h - i - 1) +
      s.repeat(i + 1).split('').join(' ') +
      ' '.repeat(h - i - 1))
    .join('\n');
}

console.log(pyramid(3));
console.log(pyramid(4));
console.log(pyramid(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be many solution for this problem.
we can use for loop, while loop, even recursive function to solve this problem.

Solution with Recursive function:

This basically treat every row as a string runs the function until `row === n`

```js
function pyramid(n, row=0, str=''){

    if(row === n){
        return;
    }

    if(str.length === (n * 2) - 1){
        console.log(str);
        pyramid(n, row+1)
        return;
    }

    const midpoint = Math.floor(((n * 2) -1) / 2)

    let add;

    if(midpoint - row <= str.length && midpoint + row >= str.length){
        add = '*'
    }else{
        add = ' '
    }

    pyramid(n, row, str + add)
}

pyramid(5)
```